# Passing Vue.js form data to Nodemailer script with Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some form data in one of my Vue components that I want to pass on to my Nodemailer script so that data can be sent as an email. I'm trying to use Axios to do this.

Nothing is happening though as I don't actually know what I'm doing!

The Nodemailer script I have set up works when I execute the file in the command line. What I need is for it to execute when the form in my Vue.js component is submitted.

Here is my Nodemailer script -

```
"use strict";
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
require('dotenv').config();

// async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper
async function main() {

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: process.env.user, // generated ethereal user
      pass: process.env.password, // generated ethereal password
    },
  });

  // send mail with defined transport object
  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: process.env.user, // sender address
    to: process.env.email, // list of receivers
    subject: 'Translation Suggestion', // Subject line
    text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
    html: "<p>Traditional: <br> Simplified: <br> Pinyin: <br> English: "
          
  });

  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
  // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>

  // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
  console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
  // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

And the function being called upon submit in my form component -

```
<button type="submit" @click="sendEmail" class="form__btn">Suggest</button>

sendEmail () {
          axios.post("localhost:3000/send-translation-suggest-email", () => {
            this.traditional,
            this.simplified,
            this.pinyin,
            this.english
          })
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the backend handler on the server that specifies the handling of `POST`-requests at `send-translation-suggest-email`, and are you sure it is executed?

Comment: What are you trying to pass as parameters to [`axios.post()`](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example)? The second should probably not be a function, but an object. To fix it, you may just remove the `() =>`-part that is declaring the arrow function, and leave the `js-object` (specified by `{}`), where you should then give keys to the properties like: `{traditional: this.traditional, simplified: this.simplified [etc...]}`.

Comment: @STh How do I add the backend handler on the server? I'm not sure how to execute it which is probably part of the problem. I've changed the second argument to what you suggested.

Comment: First of all, you will need a server with a [REST-API](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/api/what-is-a-rest-api). This might be easiest with [express.js](https://expressjs.com/). The express app will have to be separate from the vue app, so in another folder. Then you can add a listener to your route ([Hello world with express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)), which will invoke the method. You may also want to take a look at [this resource on how to setup an express server](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_restful_apis.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a [REST-API](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/api/what-is-a-rest-api) with [express.js](https://expressjs.com/), first initialize a node.js-project (`npm init [-y]`). Then you install `express.js` (`npm install express`).

When you have your setup, you can create an `index.js`-file, the server. In it, you will have to adapt the content of the [express Hello World example](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html), so that the route it accepts is not `GET /` but `POST /send-translation-suggest-email`. Then make sure your server listens to **port 3000** (as you specified in the client-side code).

In the listener to `POST /send-translation-suggest-email`, you can call the `main`-method from your other file (make sure to import the file properly, with [`node.js`'s `require`-syntax](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)).

Then, you can call the backend server from the frontend as you wished.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm not sure I want to install Express just for this one feature of my app though. If I do, I'll follow this guide. I'm going to see if I have any luck with Email JS.

Comment: Well, since you obviously want to contact a backend server (which is pretty much the only reason to use axios), I assumed you wanted help creating this server. If you don't, you could try to invoke your `main()`-method from the frontend instead of contacting a server with axios. Just make sure the script is somewhere in your frontend project and you import it correctly.